# Not start gdm: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner

Tags: gui, gdm, 19.04

Ubuntu 19.04

After restart OS start only terminal

Not Start GUI,

I have to

systemctl start gdm

GDM start good.

But how solve this problem?

```
Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
```

p.s.

in systemlog this information

```
May 25 18:09:10 work01 kernel: [   55.425632] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
May 25 18:09:10 work01 gsd-xsettings[2129]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
May 25 18:09:10 work01 gsd-color[1736]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Не удалось открыть файл «/home/drno/.local/share/icc/edid-e26a98613e7602c285572b9300e00997.icc»: Отказано в доступе
May 25 18:09:10 work01 gsd-sharing[2143]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
May 25 18:09:10 work01 gsd-sharing[2143]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
May 25 18:09:10 work01 gsd-sharing[2143]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
May 25 18:09:10 work01 gnome-session-binary[1870]: Entering running state
May 25 18:09:10 work01 dbus-daemon[1867]: [session uid=1000 pid=1867] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.54' (uid=1000 pid=2217 comm="gdbus call -e -d org.freedesktop.DBus -o /org/free" label="unconfined")
May 25 18:09:10 work01 systemd[1839]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
May 25 18:09:10 work01 dbus-daemon[1867]: [session uid=1000 pid=1867] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
May 25 18:09:10 work01 systemd[1839]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
May 25 18:09:10 work01 tracker-store.desktop[2217]: (uint32 1,)
May 25 18:09:11 work01 dbus-daemon[1867]: [session uid=1000 pid=1867] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.15' (uid=1000 pid=2004 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
May 25 18:09:11 work01 dbus-daemon[1867]: [session uid=1000 pid=1867] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
May 25 18:09:11 work01 dbus-daemon[1867]: [session uid=1000 pid=1867] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7' unit='evolution-calendar-factory.service' requested by ':1.22' (uid=1000 pid=2043 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-calendar-server " label="unconfined")
May 25 18:09:11 work01 systemd[1839]: Starting Evolution calendar service...
May 25 18:09:11 work01 dbus-daemon[1867]: [session uid=1000 pid=1867] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7'
May 25 18:09:11 work01 systemd[1839]: Started Evolution calendar service.
May 25 18:09:11 work01 dbus-daemon[1867]: [session uid=1000 pid=1867] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook9' unit='evolution-addressbook-factory.service' requested by ':1.59' (uid=1000 pid=2256 comm="/usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory " label="unconfined")
May 25 18:09:11 work01 systemd[1839]: Starting Evolution address book service...
May 25 18:09:11 work01 dbus-daemon[1867]: [session uid=1000 pid=1867] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook9'
May 25 18:09:11 work01 systemd[1839]: Started Evolution address book service.
May 25 18:09:11 work01 NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1558796951.3117] agent-manager: req[0x55ab4f472060, :1.267/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
May 25 18:09:11 work01 gnome-shell[2004]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
May 25 18:09:11 work01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2004]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
May 25 18:09:11 work01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2004]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
```

Comment: Linux work01 5.0.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 17:41:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: having the same issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I had this same issue!

Ok, not exactly the same, but I spent most of yesterday trying to find the solution, I edited so many files and deleted others, **nothing**, but then I found out that it was the driver version I was running.

---

I was running the nvidia-440 driver, which apparently is still a little unstable, all I had to do to restore everything was downgrade to nvidia-435.
**NOTE**: *These steps might not work if your not using nvidia.*
**NOTE**: *If you aren't experienced with the Terminal or Linux in general,* **Then please go to the "*step by step for beginners*" section.**

---

#### Here's the step by step:

- **Step 1**:

  - Open "*Software & Updates*", and open the "*Additional Drivers*" tab.
- **Step 2**:

  - Switch to the latest driver available, *If it isn't already in use*, Otherwise switch to the previous driver version from the one in use.
    *Example*: **nvidia-*35 -> nvidia-*40**, or **nvidia-*40 -> nvidia-*35**.
    **NOTE**: *Make sure to click <kbd>Apply Changes</kbd> after selecting the driver.*
- **Step 3**:

  - Open "*Synaptic Package Manager*" and search for "**nvidia**".
    **NOTE**: *Make sure that the search is filtered to "**Name**" and not "**Description & Name**".*
    **NOTE**: *You can filter the packages by **Installed Packages** first by clicking the upper left box on the main package window, marked with an "**S**", once.*
- **Step 4**:

  - Find all the installed packages that are labeled with the old driver version and uninstall them.
    **NOTE**: *If you don't do this your computer might have **major issues** when you reboot, but it sometimes works without this.  One of the issues can make your computer incredibly hard to fix without completely reinstalling your system.*
- **Step 5**:
  **NOTE**: *I don't know if this step is required, but I did this just before my computer started working again.*

  - Look for **linux-modules-nvidia-****-generic**, the description should be headed by "*Extra drivers for nvidia-435 for the generic flavour*".
    **NOTE**: *If you are using another kernel flavor, then pick the package for that flavor instead.*
- **Step 6**:

  - Reboot.
- **Step 7**:

  - Open up the *Terminal* and run,
    `sudo apt-get update`
  - then run,
    `sudo apt-get upgrade`
  - And if you had *nvidia-settings* installed before the driver change, run.
    `sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings`

---

#### Here's the step by step for beginners:

- **Step 1**: 
  <kbd>Open the *Application Overview* with <kbd>super</kbd>, or <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, and type "*drivers*", click on "*Software & Updates*" and open the "*Additional Drivers*" tab, *Wait for the driver options to load*.

  [image: Additional Drivers]</kbd>
- **Step 2**: 
  <kbd>Switch to the latest driver available, *If it isn't already in use*, Otherwise switch to the previous driver version from the one in use.

  *Example*: **nvidia-*35 -> nvidia-*40**, or **nvidia-*40 -> nvidia-*35**.

  [image]</kbd>
  **NOTE**: *Make sure to click <kbd>Apply Changes</kbd> after selecting the driver.*
  <kbd>[image: Apply Drivers]</kbd>
  **NOTE**: *If the <kbd>Apply Changes</kbd> button is greyed out it probably means you haven't selected a driver yet.*
- **Step 3**:
  <kbd>Open "*Synaptic Package Manager*" and search for "**nvidia**".

  [image]</kbd>
  **NOTE**: *Make sure that the search is filtered to "**Name**" and not "**Description & Name**".*
  <kbd>[image]</kbd>
  **NOTE**: *You can filter the packages by installed first by clicking the upper left box on the main package window, marked with an "**S**", once.*
  <kbd>[image]</kbd>
- **Step 4**:

  - Find all the installed packages that are labeled with the old driver version and uninstall them.
    *Example*: *If you were using the "**nvidia-430**" driver then you would uninstall anything marked with "**430**"*
    **NOTE**: *If you don't do this your computer might have **major issues** when you reboot, but it sometimes works without this.  One of the issues can make your computer incredibly hard to fix without completely reinstalling.*
- **Step 5**:
  **NOTE**: *I don't know if this step is required, but I did this just before my computer started working again.*

  - Look for **linux-modules-nvidia-****-generic** the description should be headed by "*Extra drivers for nvidia-**** for the generic flavour*".
    **NOTE**: *The asterisks stand for the driver version you are using, like 435 or 350.*
    **NOTE**: *If you are using another kernel flavor, then pick the package for that flavor instead.*
- **Step 6**:

  - Reboot.
- **Step 7**:

  - Open up the *Terminal* with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, and run,
    `sudo apt-get update`
    <kbd>[image: sudo apt-get update]</kbd>
  - then run,
    `sudo apt-get upgrade`
    <kbd>[image: sudo apt-get upgrade]</kbd>
  - And if you had *nvidia-settings* installed before the driver change, run.
    `sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings`
    <kbd>[image: sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings]</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I already use ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I wish I could have helped you a year ago.

Comment: how stable is 20.04 right now?  I still haven’t upgraded from 18.04 and am a little hesitant to upgrade yet...